# Prove: $\gcd(n^a-1,n^b-1)=n^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm trying to prove the following statement:
$$\forall_{a,b\in\Bbb{N^{+}}}\gcd(n^a-1,n^b-1)=n^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$$

As for now I managed to prove that $n^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$ divdes $n^a-1$ and $n^b-1$:

Without loss of generality let $a>b$ (if $a=b$, the result is obvious), $n\neq1$ ($\gcd(0,0)$ makes no sense). Then if we let $a=kd, b=jd, d=\gcd(a,b)$, we see that for $n^{kd}-1$ we have $\frac{(n^d)^k-1}{n^d-1}=1+n^d+...+n^{d(k-1)}=C$ (it's a finite geometric series), so $n^a-1=(n^d-1)C$. Same works for $n^b-1$, so $n^d-1$ divides both of these numbers.

How to prove that $n^d-1$ not only divides both numbers, but is greatest common divisor?

Comment: You missed a "$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+$". =)

Comment: Thanks, it's corrected now.

Comment: Nope it's not. It still doesn't specify what is $n$. And depending on how you define $\gcd$ you may have $\gcd(0,0) = 0$.

Comment: $n$ is a natural number greater than 0

Comment: Yes I know that, but since you specified what $a,b$ are you should have also specified $n$. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

First prove that $\gcd(x,y) = \gcd(x,y-ax)$ for any $x,y,a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x,y$ are not both zero. Then use this repeatedly in the simplest possible way to actually 'compute' $\gcd(n^a-1,n^b-1)$. It will naturally come out to be $n^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$.

Then for extra fun try the same method to find $\gcd(n^a+1,n^b+1)$.